# Compensation based on Tasks vs Hours for Intern

Tags: compensation, hours

I am working as software engineer at a small startup in SF. I'm paid by the hour but am wondering if this is the best way to be compensated for my time/work.

I feel like at times because I am paid for my time regardless of what I'm doing I am dis-incentivized from working efficiently/very hard and instead end up spending more time completing projects than I could if I was 'sprinting'.

I am considering asking my employer about some type of fixed salary, in which I am compensated based on project completion rather than the amount of time I spend at work, so that I can spend less time at work but spend that time more efficiently, so as to use my time more wisely.

***Is this a reasonable request? Does a task based compensation system hold merit? How should I frame the request/proceed? Am I just being lazy?***

*To clarify, I am currently working hard. I add value to the company I work for, and it's not like i'm not working while at the job*

Comment: Could it be the real issue is either (a) you are not feeling properly motivated (enough), or (b) you feel you are being paid too little. If it is either of those, say which one and maybe there is a different solution.

Comment: a salary is not based on "project completion"  you need to brush up on the difference between the two https://www.thebalance.com/salary-vs-hourly-employee-397909

Comment: This can 100% surely backfire. Imagine asking them can I just be paid fixed so I can drag my feet less when completing tasks? This  is going to sound bad and cast a shadow on your work quality/ethics so far for sure. You need to be very considerate with how you word this if you go that way in the end.

Comment: If you want to experiment with that form of payment and still be considered "an employee" rather than a independent contractor, you can always try sales. Salespeople get paid entirely on commission. You make more sales, your cut is bigger. It can really add up and it is a highly respected role for those that can make it-- the ones that don't promptly get fired or quit by starvation.

Comment: Are you trying to have a shorter work day overall or are you trying to spend less of your work day on programming/project tasks so you can spend time on other work priorities?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a reasonable request?

No, not in the context of a software startup employee.

> Does a task based compensation system hold merit?

Sure. There are many projects that get put out to bid to contractors and subcontractors this way. Not so much for employees in startup software companies.

> How should I frame the request/proceed?

If you really want to try this, you should quit and form your own company (for example, freelance).

Bid on **fixed-price projects/tasks**.

Then you will be "compensated based on project completion". Whether or not that will let you "spend less time at work but spend that time more efficiently, so as to use my time more wisely" depends on your abilities, and the kinds of tasks you bid on.

And as @HLGEM wisely points out - there is a time cost to being a freelancer that you should consider. There are no free lunches.

> Am I just being lazy?

I don't know.

If you are just looking for a quick way to work fewer hours without earning less, then laziness may be the issue, or perhaps just a lack of experience.

Working for yourself will prove to you if you can accomplish what you are seeking. You will soon find out if you are lazy or not.

Comment: Of course, if you quit and go for fixed price contracts, you will need to spend all the extra time doing billing/accounting and marketing and looking for new projects as one is getting ready to complete.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that there was a time cost to doing freelancing.I agree that it seems to suit the OPs attitude towards work.

Comment: Don't forget to include the risk of inaccurately estimating how long a fixed price freelancing job will take and ending up spending 2 or 3x (or more) the time on it than you expected.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is an unreasonable request.  An *employer* reserves the right to have your butt in a chair to not only write code, but support the efforts of the department (read: **team**) as things happen throughout the work week.  That means pitching in with others during crunch time, and actually participating in efforts that benefit people beside *yourself*.

The employer also reserves the right to redirect your work - within reason - at a moment's notice to other pressing needs within your scope of expertise, and you being out-of-the-loop is a deterrent.  Lastly, no one really likes a smart a-- guy on the team who's always trying to cut corners and exact privileges that no one else on the team has; one day, you'll need help.  Treat your team with respect.

Answer (score 0):

If he did say yes, you'd regret it almost immediately.  What's a task?  Does a more difficult task pay more?  Who decides how much a task is worth?  What if midway through you realize its twice as difficult as you think it is?  Does a time consuming but not difficult task pay more?  Who decides how long it will take?  What's the definition of "done"?  Code complete, merged to prod, unit tested, etc?  What if there's bug fixes-  are those new tasks or are you not done with the previous one?  What if requirements change?

You're just asking to get raked over the coals financially this way.